# Xcode doesn't give output and is stuck compiling

Tags: c, xcode

[Here, on the bottom, there is just a blank screen, while on the top left i can see xcode is still compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gte2X.png)[Here the same code, once i copied and pasted it on a brand new c file. There is no problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxOrU.jpg)

I really can't understand what's going on here. I've written a program in C that does stuff with college grades, just basic math, and that works fine. But after a certain amount of times i run the program, every time i try to run it xcode just stops working and gives me nothing as an output, as shown in the pictures.

Now, my mac and xcode are both updated, and all i did countless times was just copy and paste the entire code in a new file and just run it again. That's to be noted that this problem shows up only with this program, it never occured with other ones.

i could upload chunks of code but i personally don't think that's necessary, since it's basic c stuff. But i'm just an amateur and i could be wrong, and i will happily upload some code, but i ultimately think that there is some problem with some setting in xcode.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your project settings have a huge impact on how code is run. If one project is a library it won't actually "run" anything, it will compile and make a library file, for example. Check which "Target" types you have defined.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Setting up targets is hard to explain in a comment, but the good news is there's a lot of material on how to do that in the XCode documentation and other online tutorials.